# Merge conflict on unchanged files when working on the same branch

Tags: git, branch, git-merge-conflict

Two people, A and B, are working on the same branch.
Person A pushes changes on file X to the branch. Person B has not touched file X and does `git pull`.
This resulted in a merge conflict on file X.
Why does this happen, and how does person B avoid, or handle this situation?

Comment: Something *has* changed file X on the copy of the branch that B has. Or there wouldn't be a merge conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person B should inspect the history of his local branch, compared to the history of the remote branch :

```sh
git log --oneline --graph <branch> origin/<branch>

# you possibly want to only see what commits impacted file X :
git log --oneline --graph <branch> origin/<branch> -- X

# generic shortcuts :
#  - "the commit I'm currently on" is HEAD
#  - "the tracked upstream branch" is @{u}
git log --oneline --graph HEAD @{u}
```

I suggested terminal commands to view the history, most of GUI frontends also allow to view the combined history of several branches.

---

Possibilities include (but are not limited to) :

- person A committing her changes with `commit --amend` or `rebase`, and uploading her changes using `push -f`,
- person B having rewritten part of her local history (e.g : `commit --amend` or `rebase`) before pulling.

I don't really see how a conflict can occur without a history change, but perhaps I overlooked some possibility. Anyway : the history view should highlight something.

---

The most appropriate way to "fix" this situation depends on what you see in the history, some generic ways are :

- person B can rebase her changes on top of the most recent version of the remote branch ; if there are redundant commits to drop, she can use `rebase --interactive`, and mark "drop" in front of said commits
- person B can simply fix conflicts in the merge she has ; if she knows for sure that the correct version for file X is the one pushed by person A, she can run :

```
# remove the "conflicting" flags :
git reset -- X
# use the version from the remote branch :
git checkout origin/<branch> -- X
```

Comment: Thank you, I think `git reset -- X` is the one I was more or less looking for, as I was 100% sure the changes from A were to be kept.